# How to numerically sort an array of strings?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings that has a number at the beginning, followed by a name.  How can I sort the array numerically; ie

```
40 Mike, 25 Tyson, 9 Jackson, 5 Phillip, 3 Mitchell
```

as opposed to

```
9 Jackson, 5 Phillip, 40 Mike, 3 Mitchell, 25 Tyson
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: "*followed by a name*"... I can't see any?

Comment: Okay, I'll add the name.  I've tried using the built in alphabetical sort, which returns the bottom sample.

Comment: may be `IComparer` can help. Have a look at [Numeric String Sort in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] items = {"10", "1", "30", "-5"};
        Array.Sort(items, (x, y) => 
        {
            int xNum = int.Parse(x);
            int yNum = int.Parse(y);
            return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(xNum, yNum);
        });

        foreach(var item in items)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't see your update when I wrote the code.. but it will still work if instead of "int.Parse" you will put function that "Extracts" the number out of the string.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned the fact that the names have to stay with the numbers.  Or am I misinterpreting your response?  Also, I apologize that my question was not clear enough, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: They will stay with the numbers. Array.Sort() will not touch your strings. It will only swap items using the provided comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sorted = yourArray.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split()[0])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SortedDictionary data structure to obtain an array sorted.